# How should we actually define constants with namespaces in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, pep8

I've always defined constants with Python 3 like below:

```py
class SomeMeaningFulNameSpaceName:
    FOO = "foo"
    BAR = "bar"
```

But when I recently started running all of my code through [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint) I found out that this generates a refactoring suggestion:

```
[R0903(too-few-public-methods), SomeMeaningFulNameSpaceName] Too few public methods (0/2)
```

How should namespace encapsulation of constants be actually done or is this just a limitation of Pylint?

Comment: The most natural way is to use a *module*, so just add `FOO = 'foo'` and `BAR = 'bar'` inside a `some_meaningful_namespace.py` and use that. Alternatively, you can use a`types.SimpleNamespace` as well. Or better yet, *simply ignore pylint*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Your edit doesn't seem to have made the question worth reopening. It's a good edit, but it pushed the question into the reopen queue for no good reason. It might make sense to avoid edits to closed questions if the edit doesn't change the close-worthiness of the question.